# Set isClickable to false for a button in the ListView after the first click Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have created a Custom Adapter for a ListView and each element in the listview has 1 TextView and 1 Button

### ListView

### [TextView 1] [Button 1]

### [TextView 2] [Button 2]

..(so on)

My requirement:
You are allowed to click button only once. It's like 'Like' button.After the first click, isClickable only for the button in that row should be set to false.

Mycode:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup   parent)  {      
    View row=convertView; 
    ViewHolder holder=null;
    if(row==null)
    {                   
        row=msgInflator.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(row);
        holder.msg=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        holder.up=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.upVote);

        holder.up.setTag(holder);
        holder.up.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewHolder hold=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
                hold.up.setClickable(false);
            }
        });
        row.setTag(holder);         
    }
    else
    {
        holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();            
    }   
    holder.msg.setText(messages.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.up.setText(messages.get(position).getUp());
    return row;
}
```

Problem:

When i click on Button 1:

Button 1 isClickable set to false -> which is required

Few other Buttons (ex: Button 5,6) isClickable is also set to false -> Which is undesired

How can i achieve my required output?

Comment: Does it happen when you scroll? Or even without scrolling?

Comment: In the both the cases

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works, its can help you, you should add one property to your DS and change that

Comment: @Ravindra take a look at my answer and try it out. If everything works and you need more explanation please let me know. If some problems with my code.. also please comment below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution, with two main changes:

1) Maintain a list of button positions that have been disabled. Every time, you click on a button, store its position in the list.

2) Move the `onClickListener` out of `if/else` and set it every time. This ensures that despite views being reused, the position is up-to-date.

```
ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup   parent)  {      
    View row=convertView; 
    ViewHolder holder=null;
    if(row==null)
    {                   
        row=msgInflator.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(row);
        holder.msg=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        holder.up=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.upVote);

        row.setTag(holder);         
    }
    else
    {
        holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();            
    }   
    holder.msg.setText(messages.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.up.setText(messages.get(position).getUp());
    holder.up.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button btn = (Button)v;
            btn.setClickable(false);
            positions.add(position)
        }
    });
    if(positions.contains(new Integer(position))) {
        holder.up.setClickable(false);
    }
    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the behavior of `ListView`. To have `ListView` performs as optimized as possible, Android team deploys `View` reusing technique in `ListView` intensively.

This mean, the `Button` you're using in row N, may be reuse again in row N+12. So, you need to update your Button's state everytime `getView` is being triggered.

Here's what you can do.

```
    if (off.contains(position)) {
        hold.up.setClickable(false);
    } else {
        hold.up.setClickable(true);
    }

    if (row==null)
    {   
        ...
        holder.up.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // off is Set<Integer>
                off.add(position);
            }
        });
        ....
```